# xunit.net tests discovered & run but "an exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2/uap'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, xunit.net

I have added a new xUnit.net test project and added some tests to it. All tests are being discovered and run but in the Tests output window, I get the exception:

> An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://xunit/VsTestRunner2/uap': Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Package'.
>   Operation is not supported on this platform.
>   [xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (32-bit Desktop .NET 4.0.30319.42000)

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional edition, .Net framework 4.6 on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Paddy. No, I left that project but this didn't occur in later projects I worked on (Windows 10 Pro, VS 2019 Prof). So, something specific to the previous project/environment settings, maybe.